# What is a good and SIMPLE chips view library

Tags: android, tags, material-design, android-chips

I have searched everywhere to find the Chips View library that I need.

The Chips need to be displayed inside an EditText with Autocomplete function. I have tried https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips and https://github.com/DoodleScheduling/android-material-chips but they think I will be using there library for Contacts (or email addresses). That is not the case, I'll be using them for Tags (with 1 word and 1 icon).
I have tried to make my own version of both of the libraries, but they are way to complicated.

Does anybody know a good Chips View library that has the same functionality and looks the same?

Comment: HI.. Did you find any solution for same? I am also checking for same chips lib with custom view.

Comment: @Beena Nope I haven't. I think I am going to give up the search for a good one.

Comment: For future readers https://github.com/robertlevonyan/materialChipView seems a good choice!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement material chips using this library: https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete.

It works with custom data (you have to implement your own view) and is very extensible.

```
public class ContactsCompletionView extends TokenCompleteTextView<Person> {

    ...

    @Override
    protected View getViewForObject(Person person) {
        LayoutInflater l = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        TokenTextView token = (TokenTextView) l.inflate(R.layout.contact_token, (ViewGroup) getParent(), false);
        token.setText(person.getEmail());
        return token;
    }
}
```